# How can I enable my laptop to receive HTTP requests over port 8080 on my private network?

Tags: web-services, localhost, development-environment

I'm behind a router and I have a web service hosted on Tomcat on my laptop. It's running on port 8080. I want my phone, also connected to my home network to be able to send HTTP requests to my laptop on port 8080. I installed a REST service app on my phone that allows me to send customized HTTP requests to wherever, and I tried sending it to `192.168.1.20:8080/web-service/test`, where `192.168.1.20` is the address of my laptop on my home network and `/web-service/test` is the url I'm using to interact with the web-service, but I keep getting an "invalid request" message. When I access the web-service through that url using `localhost:8080/web-service/test` on my laptop the text that's printed in the browser is "running," but not when accessed through the phone.

I also tried pinging my laptop from my phone using another app and the ping is successful. The firewall is turned off and network sharing is on (windows 10). Anyone have any idea why I cannot access the web-service using `192.168.1.20:8080/web-service/test`?

Comment: You may need to forward the port in your router configuration.

Comment: @wrwrwr what if i don't have access to the router's configuration? can i do this through windows 10? also if i'm not accessing my laptop from outside the network why would i have to set up port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the rest api testing app i was using on my phone. for some reason it was showing me an "invalid request" message even if the same url worked when i visited it from the chrome app. but basically it was working the entire time.